# Having problems applying TDD to XML parser project

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, parsing, tdd

I know usually you are supposed to make a failing test then write the code to make the test fail before actually coding the project but we did backwards.  Tests are new and still very hard to write for our group.  We have our XMLParser class working exactly as it should, the XMLPaserTester class has a xml string hard coded into it because what we are testing changes each time you run the parser retrieving 3 most recent updates to wiki pages.

```
public class XMLParser {

private WikipediaConnection wC= new WikipediaConnection();
private String XML;
private String[] XMLArray;
private String firstRecentChange;
private String secondRecentChange;
private String thirdRecentChange;

private void findNecessaryXMLPart()
{
    try {
        XML = wC.makeXMLFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    XMLArray = XML.split("recentchanges>");
    XML = XMLArray[1];
}

private String findTitle(String string, int titleNumber)
{
    String[] titleSplit =  XML.split("title=\"");
    String[] titleSplitAgain = titleSplit[titleNumber].split("\" timestamp=\"");

    return titleSplitAgain[0];
}

private Date findTimestamp(String string, int timestampNumber)
{
    String[] timestampSplit = XML.split("timestamp=\"");
    String[] timestampSplitAgain = timestampSplit[timestampNumber].split("\" comment=\"");

    return timeConverter(timestampSplitAgain[0]);
}
private String findComment(String string, int commentNumber)
{
    String[] commentSplit = XML.split("comment=\"");
    String[] commentSplitAgain = commentSplit[commentNumber].split("/><");

    return "\"" + commentSplitAgain[0];
}

private Date timeConverter(String string)
{
    String[] dateAndTime = string.split("T");
    String date = dateAndTime[0];
    String time = dateAndTime[1];

    DateTimeFormatter formatOfISOFormat=DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSZ");
    Date recentChange = formatOfISOFormat.parseDateTime(date + "T" + time)
                                                    .toDate();
    return recentChange;
}

private String stringConstructor(String string, int number)
{
    String title = findTitle(string, number);
    Date timestamp = findTimestamp(string, number);
    String comment = findComment(string, number);

    String constructedString = title + " was modified on " + timestamp + ". The comment is "
            + comment + ".";
    return constructedString;
}
public String toString()
{
    findNecessaryXMLPart();

    firstRecentChange = stringConstructor(firstRecentChange, 1);
    secondRecentChange = stringConstructor(secondRecentChange, 2);
    thirdRecentChange = stringConstructor(thirdRecentChange, 3);

    return firstRecentChange + "\n" + secondRecentChange + 
            "\n" + thirdRecentChange;
}
}
```

I planned to make a test case to capture the title, time, and comment just figuring out 1 the same concept should be able to be applied to the other 2.  When I run the test it comes back as red, giving me the error expected []Kasumi (Dead or Alive) actual [title="]Kasumi (Dead or Alive)

```
public class XMLParserTester{

private static String XMLRecentChangesString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><api><query-continue><recentchanges rccontinue=\"2014-02-03T13:40:21Z|634981610\" /></query-continue><query><recentchanges><rc type=\"edit\" ns=\"0\" title=\"Kasumi (Dead or Alive)\" timestamp=\"2014-02-03T13:40:24Z\" comment=\"/* Critical acclaim and popularity */\" /><rc type=\"edit\" ns=\"0\" title=\"Comparison of file archivers\" timestamp=\"2014-02-03T13:40:23Z\" comment=\"/* General information */ removed preview releases from 7-zip &amp; freearc &amp; KGB\" /><rc type=\"edit\" ns=\"0\" title=\"Colin Firth on stage and screen\" timestamp=\"2014-02-03T13:40:21Z\" comment=\"\" /></recentchanges></query></api>";
private String[] XMLArray;



@Test
public void testTitle(){
    XMLArray = XMLRecentChangesString.split("ns=\"0\"");
    XMLRecentChangesString = XMLArray[1];
    String[] titleSplit =  XMLRecentChangesString.split("title=\"\"");
    int titleNumber = 0;
    String[] titleSplitAgain = titleSplit[titleNumber].split("\" timestamp=\"");
    Assert.assertEquals("Kasumi (Dead or Alive)", titleSplitAgain[0]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unit test is used to test the functionality offered by some class, always through the public methods of this class, in your test you are doing something like duplicating the code in your production class, this its not very useful, for example:

```
 public void
 test_can_get_the_3_most_recent_changes_in_wikipedia() {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser() // object under test

    assertEquals(parser, "....") // compare the result of parser with the string you expect

 }
```

This test reveals some problems in the design of your class (this is the real benefit of TDD!):

- use toString() to return the 3 most recent changes its really strange, why not a method "mostRecentChanges" that return a list??
- this line: 
    private WikipediaConnection wC= new WikipediaConnection();
  Your class are strongly coupled with "wikipediaConnection", you cannot test this class in isolation    without a real connection with the wikipedia. You are breaking one of the SOLID rules: dependency injection, a class must depends in abstractions not in concrete classes.

a better test with this changes:

```
 public void
 test_can_get_the_3_most_recent_changes_in_wikipedia() {

    WikipediaConnection mockConnection = mock(WikepediaConnection.class);
    when(mockConnection.makeXMLFile()).thenReturn("your test xml"); // use mockito

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(mockConnection) // inject the dependency in constructor

    assertThat(parser.mostRecentChanges(), allOf(
       contains("one_change_you_expect"),
       contains("the_sencond..."),
       contains("the_third")
    ); // use hamcrest for clear test expectations

 }
```

This is a good test for your XMLParser, test your class real functionality through the public interface and helps you identifying problems in your design (the test still reveals some problems, like the name XMLParser that is really a bad name because its too generic).

With your first attempt to testing in mind, i think that your team need some help with this, read some good books (like tdd by example or Growing object oriented guided by test) or hire someone with real experience in TDD.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `String` with a `String[]` (an array). Assuming the expected string is in the first position in your array, you would write:

```
Assert.assertEquals("Kasumi (Dead or Alive)", titleSplit[0]);
```

EDIT

Here is what I would do. I would first change the method to make it more testable (it does not have to be static but because I have removed the dependency on the class' state it can be static, so let's do it):

```
//@VisibleForTesting is a guava annotation that makes your intention clear
//it is obviously not required

@VisibleForTesting
static String findTitle(String xml, int titleNumber) {
    String[] titleSplit =  xml.split("title=\"");
    String[] titleSplitAgain = titleSplit[titleNumber].split("\" timestamp=\"");

    return titleSplitAgain[0];
}
```

And your test could look like:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> ...";
assertEquals("Kasumi (Dead or Alive)", XMLParser, findTitle(xml, 0));
```

Comment: hanks that got me a little closer but actual showed up as rc type=\"edit\" ns=\"0\" so I changed where it started splitting at now its giving me very close to what I want but its giving me [title="]Kasumi (Dead or Alive) and its expecting it without the title= not sure how to remove that part. Took it out title= of split and it still gave me the same result. `XMLArray = XMLRecentChangesString.split("ns=\"0\"");` `String[] titleSplit = XMLRecentChangesString.split("title=\"\"");`

Comment: @user3275821 To be honest this is very confusing - you are reimplenting your class logic in your test instead of testing your class itself... Why don't you make `findTitle` pachage-private to be able to test it and test `Assert.assertEquals("Kasumi (Dead or Alive)", xmlParser.findTitle(...));`?

Comment: Unit testing is still very new to us so I probably do lots of it wrong, I tried doing it that way after you mentioned it changing the XMLParser String xml to static, the method findtitle to public static, and in the test class the xmlrecentchanges string to public but it gave me a null pointer error.

Comment: @DanB Well yes because you need to instatiate XML. See my edit.